Can the power n of nilpotent matrices express all possible matrices with n diagonals empty?
I have this idea from Serge Lang's Algebra. In page 19 it says:
Let $N$ be the additive group of matrices which are $0$ on and below the diagonal (aka nilpotent upper triangular). ...
observe that for $r\geq 2$, the set $N^{r-1}$ consists of all matrices of the form
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \cdots & 0 & a_{1,r} & a_{1,r+1} & \cdots & a_{1,n} \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & a_{2,r+1} & \cdots & a_{2,n} \\
\vdots &  &  &  &  & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 &  &  &  &  &  & a_{n-r+1,n} \\
0 &  &  & \cdots &  &  & 0 \\
\vdots &  &  &  &  &  & \vdots \\
0 &  &  & \cdots &  &  & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
If we consider this $N^{r-1}$ to mean $\{A^{r-1},A\in N\}$, then can this express all of the matrices of the given form? That is, for a matrix of this form, does it always have a $(r-1)$th root? If so, how do we prove it and do we have any restrictions on the fields? If not, is there an example?
(ps: In the book, this is not important, since we can just define the $N^{r-1}$ to be so and it's not relevant to the theme. But the "observe" bothers me - shouldn't this mean a proposition instead of a definition?)

Does Lang give the same definition of $N^{r-1}$ as yours? It could be ${A_1\cdots A_r, A_i\in N}$ ?

Well he didn't. Your definition is much better. However, my definition might be an interesting question.

I think Lang uses my definition (with $A_1\cdots A_{r-1}$) because in page 6 he says: "If $S$ and $S'$ are two subsets of a monoid we define $SS' = {ss', s\in S, s'\in S'}$"

It is not said but I think Serge Lang uses the definition
\begin{equation}{N}^{p} = \left\{{A}_{1} \cdots  {A}_{p} , {A}_{i} \in  N , 1  \leqslant  i  \leqslant  p\right\}\end{equation}
With this definition let
\begin{equation}A = {\left({a}_{i , j} \left[i+r-1  \leqslant  j\right]\right)}_{i , j}\end{equation}
be the matrix that you wrote in the question, where $\left[\cdots \right]$ denotes Iverson's bracket.
Let
\begin{equation}X = {\left(\left[i+1 = j\right]\right)}_{i , j} \in  N\end{equation}
It is easy to see that
\begin{equation}A = B {X}^{r-2}\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}B = {\left({a}_{i , j+r-2} \left[i+1  \leqslant  j\right]\right)}_{i , j} \in  N\end{equation}
Hence $A \in  {N}^{r-1}$.
